# Complex conditional expressions with user EasyIn.

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-statements, user-input

I wrote the following Java code and wanted to ask how do I keep asking the user for the correct distance, if the user enters distance < 0 ? Do I have to create a new variable each time or is it possible to loop the whole process and getInt, only when Distance >=0 ? Many thanks.

```
public  class   W05Practical {
public  static  void    main(String []  args)   {
    System.out.println("Please enter the lengths/distance in meters:");
    int Distance = EasyIn.getInt();

    if (Distance >= 0) {
System.out.println("Thank you");
    }
    else { 
System.out.println("Distance can not be negative. \nPlease enter the appropriate distance:");
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion for the problem. Create a boolean called correctInput and have it monitor if it is the correct input.

For example:

```
public  class   W05Practical {
    public  static  void   main(String[] args){
        boolean correctInput = false;

        while(!correctInput){
            System.out.println("Please enter the lengths/distance in meters:");
            int Distance = EasyIn.getInt();

            if (Distance >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                correctInput = true;
            }else { 
                System.out.println("Distance can not be negative. \nPlease enter the appropriate distance:");
            }  
        }    
    }
}
```